# How to set the "upper" border color on grouped UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've used `-[UITableView setSeparatorColor:]` to set the red border in the attached image. But how do I set the color of the border showing up as white?

[image]

**EDIT:** I know I can use the `UITableViewSeparatorStyleSingleLine` style to get rid of the white color entirely. But I don't want to do that: I want to change its color. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The white color is because the separator style is set to Single Line Edged. If you change it to Single Line the white lines will disappear. Not sure if that solves your problem but I don't think you change the color without doing a lot more work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. But I thought this sort of stuff was supposed to be customizable in iOS 5 without a lot of hacking around.

Answer (score 4):

Try making a "line view" for the cells. So in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method just add that to the cell that you need:

```
UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 1)] autorelease];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lineView.autoresizingMask = 0x3f;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

that will add that white line to the top of the each cell. If you don't want it for the very first row add an if-statement:

```
if (indexPath.row != 0)
{
  UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 1)] autorelease];
  lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  lineView.autoresizingMask = 0x3f;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I'm talking about the white line that's at the bottom of each cell, including the curved border. So drawing a line by itself won't quite cut it; I'll need to draw the curve as well, and draw it somehow behind the cell.

Comment: Using a magic number for autoresizingMask is something that no programmer should do. There are named constants to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the default iOS user interface but the change is so complex that it can't be done with the default properties.

What is the solution? Just remove the lines drawn by UITableVie (setting the color to `[UIColor clearColor]`) and customize UITableViewCell background.

Of course, you need 3 types of backgrounds - for the first cell, for the last cell and for the middle ones:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {  
    UITableViewCell* cell = [...];

    UIView* background;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        background = [...]; //background for the first cell
    }
    else if (indexPath.row + 1 == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]) {
        background = [...]; //background for the last cell
    }
    else {
        background = [...]; //background for the middle cells
    }

    cell.backgroundView = background;
}
```

The question is how to create the background. Usually I just use an UIImageView or a combination of several UIImageView (rounded corner as one image and the lines as resizible images).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

This built-in drawing is specific to grouped-style tableView, and can't be changed (to my knowledge...)

There's a workaround to this (we've used -> sorry no source code), but i guess you're not going to like it :

1/ have information of each cell's position
2/ to re-implement drawing of EACH cell's background, depending on its position (so you have to save this position : *FirstCell*, *MiddleCell*, *LastCell*,) to reproduce the grouped tableView look.

A way to do this is with `CoreGraphics` :

From your subclassed *CellGroupedBackgroundView* (or *customGroupedTableViewCell*, depending on the design you choose) you create 2 nearly identical CAShapeLayers. Each one for each separator color. And you expose these colors as properties of your *CellGroupedBackgroundView*.

You set these layer's path depending on the **position** property you have set (using only `CGPathAddLineToPoint`for middle cells, and `CGPathAddArcToPoint` for first and last cell)

2/ use that created custom backgroundView on a plain UITableView, setting each cell's 'position' according to its indexPath...

Good luck :)